# Unable to attach to nodemon: Could not find any debuggable target at Object.retryGetNodeEndpoint

Tags: node.js, apple-m1

First I start my node application with command `nodemon index.js` and then I use the launch configuration provided below to connect the debugger.

This is my launch.json configuration I am using to start debugging from vscode:

```
{
    "name": "Attach to nodemon",
    "port": 9229,
    "restart": true,
    "request": "attach",
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
    ],
    "type": "pwa-node"
},
```

I get an error message:

```
Error processing attach: Error: Could not connect to debug target at http://localhost:9229: Could not find any debuggable target
at Object.retryGetNodeEndpoint (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/extension.js:2:1299140)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async t (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/extension.js:2:1321232)
at async E.launch (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/extension.js:2:1338155)
at async t.Binder.captureLaunch (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/extension.js:2:1131345)
at async t.Binder._launch (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/extension.js:2:1130890)
at async Promise.all (index 5)
at async t.Binder._boot (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/extension.js:2:1129942)
at async t.default._onMessage (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/extension.js:2:1222072)
```

The same configuration has worked before, but all of sudden it no longer works.

- VSCode Version: 1.58.2
- Mac Os M1 version: 11.1 (20C69)

Stuff I've tried:

- Opening up new terminal tab or window, still same error
- Restarting vscode, still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to start your node application with command:

```
nodemon --inspect index.js
```

If you leave out the `--inspect` the debugger for whatever reason can not attach.